# Ionic/Cordova: how to record audio and get recording as data uri (base64)

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I need to record audio (15 seconds) in Ionic and return the recording as data uri (base64 string), how can I do this in Ionic/Cordova?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you post what have you achieved?

Comment: actually Im working on a full application that requires recording audio and return base64 string, I have looked everywhere and I was unable to find anything, I have checked Cordova media plugin but it only records and I cant use it to return a string of the recorded audio